# Как настроить отладку кода на C++ в RDi версии 9.5?

Tags: c++, отладка

Ранее писал и отлаживал в RDi (Rational Developer for i) программы на C, CL и RPG. Сейчас возникла задача сделать отладку программы на C++ и тут я столкнулся с проблемой. Отладчик запускается, программа останавливается для отладки, но текущее положение выполняемого кода неверно. Оно вообще не меняется при пошаговом выполнении.
Кто-то знает как это победить?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Наверное отлаживаете релизный вариант или сборка у вас завершилась неудачно и была запущена предыдущая версия прогаммы.

Comment: Сборка завершается успешно, о чем свидетельствует лог компиляции. Настройки компиляции один в один совпадают с настройками при компиляции кода на C. При этом отладка на С работает корректно, а тут такая фигня...

Comment: Ну тогда приводите версии используемых инструментов, настройки проекта, и, пошагово, его сборку и запуск чтобы указанное поведение стало воспроизводимым.

Comment: Версия RDi 9.5, подключено к серверу IBM i (сервер моего работодателя). Создал физический файл исходного кода, добавил в него мембер с атрибутом CPP, открыл, добавил код, приведенный на скриншоте. Выполнил компиляцию командой: CRTBNDCPP PGM(CSNTST/POLIGON) SRCFILE(CSNEDU/CPPSRC) SRCMBR(POLIGON) OPTION(*EVENTF) DBGVIEW(*ALL) REPLACE(*YES). Добавил в RDi Service Entry Point для программы CSNTST/POLIGON. Выполнил запуск программы из терминала: CALL CSNTST/POLIGON. Открылся отладчик.

Comment: Вот это Ваш комментарий "Версия RDi 9.5...." лучше всего вставить в текст вопроса с помощью кнопочки "править"

Comment: Отлаживайте локально на VS. А когда все заработает, то перетранслируете своим компилятором. Переделки должны быть минимальными, во всяком случае Стандарт и Страуструп нам это обещают. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Нашел причину странного поведения отладчика. Всему виной вывод в **std::cout** цифры или переменной числового типа. То есть, вот такой код вызовет глюк отладчика:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
 int i;
 i = 5;
 std::cout << "Hello" << std::endl;
 std::cout << i << std::endl;
 return 0;
}
```

Очевидно, что это глюк именно RDi, так как в "зеленом экране" отладка работает корректно.
А еще мне кажется, что это не глюк, а просто где-то в настройках RDi нужно установить или снять какую-то галочку :). Осталось найти эту настройку.